# Cannot execute SQL from inside HIVE UDF via jdbc driver

Tags: jdbc, hive, udf

This is my first post!  I've been searching for solutions to this to no avail for weeks (on and off)...

I have a java Hive UDF where I want to run SQL against Hive table to map data in memory for later use.   I have the connection information correct, but it cannot find the HiveDriver.  I have tried adding the Hive jdbc driver jar in hive and exporting it into a runnable jar.

Error below, relevant code after.

```
hive> add jar /tmp/xhUDFs.jar;
Added [/tmp/xhUDFs.jar] to class path
Added resources: [/tmp/xhUDFs.jar]
hive> CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION getRefdata as 'xhUDFs.GetRefdata';
OK
Time taken: 0.042 seconds
hive> select '06001',getRefdata('CBSAname','06001');
```

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
>           at xhUDFs.GetRefdata.getRefmap(GetRefdata.java:53)
>           at xhUDFs.GetRefdata.evaluate(GetRefdata.java:35)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.invoke(FunctionRegistry.java:954)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDFBridge.evaluate(GenericUDFBridge.java:182)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDF.initializeAndFoldConstants(GenericUDF.java:168)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.ExprNodeGenericFuncDesc.newInstance(ExprNodeGenericFuncDesc.java:233)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.TypeCheckProcFactory$DefaultExprProcessor.getXpathOrFuncExprNodeDesc(TypeCheckProcFactory.java:1093)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.TypeCheckProcFactory$DefaultExprProcessor.process(TypeCheckProcFactory.java:1312)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultRuleDispatcher.dispatch(DefaultRuleDispatcher.java:90)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultGraphWalker.dispatchAndReturn(DefaultGraphWalker.java:95)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultGraphWalker.dispatch(DefaultGraphWalker.java:79)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultGraphWalker.walk(DefaultGraphWalker.java:133)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultGraphWalker.startWalking(DefaultGraphWalker.java:110)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.TypeCheckProcFactory.genExprNode(TypeCheckProcFactory.java:209)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.TypeCheckProcFactory.genExprNode(TypeCheckProcFactory.java:153)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genAllExprNodeDesc(SemanticAnalyzer.java:10499)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genExprNodeDesc(SemanticAnalyzer.java:10455)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genSelectPlan(SemanticAnalyzer.java:3822)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genSelectPlan(SemanticAnalyzer.java:3601)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genPostGroupByBodyPlan(SemanticAnalyzer.java:8943)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genBodyPlan(SemanticAnalyzer.java:8898)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genPlan(SemanticAnalyzer.java:9743)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genPlan(SemanticAnalyzer.java:9636)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genOPTree(SemanticAnalyzer.java:10109)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.CalcitePlanner.genOPTree(CalcitePlanner.java:329)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(SemanticAnalyzer.java:10120)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.CalcitePlanner.analyzeInternal(CalcitePlanner.java:211)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.analyze(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:227)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:454)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:314)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1164)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1212)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1101)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1091)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:216)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:168)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:379)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:739)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:684)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:624)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver

Now the code snippet:

```
    try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
            Connection wConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://172.20.2.40:10000/refdata", "", "");
            Statement sql = wConn.createStatement();
            ResultSet wResult = sql.executeQuery("select distinct zipcode5,cbsa_name,msa_name,pmsa_name,region,csaname,cbsa_div_name from refdata.zip_code_business_all_16_1_2016_orc where primaryrecord='P'");
            while (wResult.next()){
                censusMap.put(wResult.getString("zipcode5"), wResult.getString("cbsa_name"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try `add jar /wherever/my/distro/is/hive/hive-jdbc-xxxxxx-standalone.jar ;`?

Comment: Also, it looks like you just want a Java HashMap to do a lookup inside an UDF, instead of running a Hive MapJoin. OK, it's always fun to see people reinvent the wheel, especially when they fail. But why JDBC? A good old CSV file stored on HDFS would be much easier to read from your Java code. You could run your DISTINCT query to feed an Hive table STORED AS TEXT then read the raw contents.

Comment: _"ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"_ you don't have the JDBC driver on the classpath of your application.

Comment: I did trying adding the JDBC driver with "add jar".  I also tried adding it to the auxlib on the edgenode and packaging it in my udf jar to get it on the class path but nothing worked.

Comment: JDBC is a much better solution because the reference data is already in Hive for other purposes.   Using a map is much better than a join because with UDFs I can join many smaller reference tables in one command and pass over a larger table - while adding some simple transformations.   Currently I have 3 working (hard coded maps since JDBC not working) and performance is significantly better over the previous version using joins.